# compressed/minified css produces empty file in git

Tags: css, git, less, codekit, git-tower

I'm using Tower for Mac to help manage my git repositories. I'm also using CodeKit to minify & compress my LESS CSS. This produces what appear to be blank files in the repo although they show a correct file size. I've tried changing `.gitattributes` to show these particular files to `binary` to no avail.

What obvious thing am I doing wrong?

Comment: I suppose none of the advices in http://delvarworld.github.io/blog/2013/08/10/dealing-with-compiled-files-in-git/ can help?

Comment: @VonC doesn't really relate to my issue, I did see that in my searches though.

Comment: Ok. Is it an issue solely with CodeKit then? (since it produces blank files)

Comment: I'm not sure if it's Tower or CodeKit. The issue seems to occur after I stage the file. The unstaged view of the content looks normal. When I stage it all the code is missing and replaced with a single blank line.

Comment: So on the `git add` then? Do you have any .gitattributes with a `smudge` script in it? (as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/2316728/6309)

Comment: No I have nothing of the sort. .gitattributes only contains `* text=auto`

Comment: It would be good to know where exactly the problem is: after staging the file, execute "git diff --staged <file>" on the command line. What does this return? For more info, you can get in touch via support[at]git-tower[dot]com